# Find generating function of series $a_{n} = 2^{n} + 3^{n} $

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Find generating function of series $a_{n} = 2^{n} + 3^{n} $

I'm having a problem with this because at first i have to find recursive equation for $a_{n}$ . I find that $a_{0} = 2$ , $a_{1} = 5$ but how do I find the rest? Also I can't simply add generating functions, I have to solve recursive equation using generating functions. First step is to find recursive equation for $a_{n}$ then some other stuff that I can handle.

Comment: "I can't simply add generating functions": why not ?

Comment: I have to solve that in specified way, then compare my result to simple sum of two generating functions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$a_n=2^n+3^n,\\
a_{n+1}=2\cdot2^n+3\cdot3^n,\\
a_{n+2}=4\cdot2^n+9\cdot3^n$$

Then we eliminate $2^n$ and $3^n$ from the above relations by

$$a_{n+2}-4a_n=5\cdot3^n,\\
a_{n+1}-2a_n=3^n$$

and

$$a_{n+2}-4a_n=5(a_{n+1}-2a_n)$$

or

$$a_{n+2}=5a_{n+1}-6a_n.$$

---

You can reach the same conclusion by noting that the characteristic polynomial has roots $2$ and $3$, hence is $$r^2-5r+6,$$ corresponding to the recurrence

$$a_{n+2}-5a_{n+1}+6a_n=0.$$

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut: I also wrote that (I wasn't done), but I wanted to show how a solution can be found by elementary means, with no knowledge of theory.

Comment: Ah, that's right then.

Comment: Incredible, thank you for explanation I guess I can solve every recursion of that type with this method.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint:**

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2^n+5^n)x^n = \sum_{n=0}^\infty (2x)^n + \sum_{n=0}^\infty (5x)^n = \frac1{1-2x} + \frac1{1-5x}$$

---

Now you can proceed to find the recursive relation:

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = \frac1{1-2x} + \frac1{1-5x} = \frac{2-7x}{1-7x+10x^2}$$

$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n - 7\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_{n-1}x^n + 10 \sum_{n=2}^\infty a_{n-2}x^n = (1-7x+10x^2)\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n = 2-7x$$

Comparing powers gives:

\begin{align}
x^0:& \quad a_0 =2\\
x^1:& \quad a_1 - 7a_0 = -7 \implies a_1 = 7\\
x^k \text{ for } k \ge 2:& \quad a_k - 7a_{k-1} + 10a_{k-2} = 0
\end{align}

Comment: I know but I have to do that in specified way that I have to find recursive equation first.

Comment: How is this a "hint"? You have the full calculation and final answer right here.

Comment: @Michał You can find the recurrence relation from the generating function. See the edit.

Comment: No,  @Michał you do not have to find the recursion equation first. The usual situation is to find the general formula from the recursion formula by first finding the generating function. But you have been given the general formula. So you reverse the process to get the generating function. If you know the general formula, you do not necessarily need to know the recursion formula to find the generating function. It this exercise, it is found very easily as mechanodroid has shown.

Comment: $a_n=2^n+3^n$, not $2^n+5^n$. (I'm guessing the $5$ came from the OP's finding that $a_1=5$.)

Comment: @Michał you can see my or Yves' answer for the recurrence relation

Comment: I'm looking at it, thank you.

Comment: @BarryCipra Whoops, yeah. This is rightfully only a hint then, though.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: What are the roots of the characteristic equation of that recursive relation?

Answer (score 0):

Looking very closely at the terms one can identify
$$a_0=2$$
$$a_1=5=3*a_0-1=3a_0-2^0$$
$$a_2=13=3a_1-2=3a_1-2^1$$
$$a_3=35=3a_2-4=3a_2-2^2$$
$$a_4=97=3a_3-8=3a_3-2^3$$
$$a_5=275=3a_4-16=3a_4-2^4$$

And in general:
$$a_{n+1}=3a_n-2^n$$

Comment: This is a mixed solution, which involves a first order recurrence and a part of the known exponential solution at the same time. You are halfway of the work I guess.

Comment: I checked it up to $a_{18}$. Works nicely

Comment: I assume you are answering me. I don't say that your relations "do not work". I say they are halfway done. The term $2^n$ should disappear.

Comment: Agreed. I wasn't sure how (and even if it was necessary) to get rid of the $2^n$ term, so I just found a way to transform it to a recurrence relation.

Comment: Now you can write $2^{n+1}=2\cdot2^n$, or $3a_{n+1}-a_{n+2}=2(3a_{n}-a_{n+1})$.